# How to hide a view with center open - like a photoframe

Tags: ios, xcode, image, mask

In an application, in settings menu i have few 'controls' with slider bars, with each item having a small help button.

if user clicks the 'help' button, only the selected 'control' should be visible, and the remaining area should be covered with a new image (this would contain control related information), like a 'photo frame'.

Can somebody suggest, how to implement this 'photo-frame' masking in iOS?

Comment: be more specific, you could just place a UIView on top of the UI elements you want to cover, make it slide or have alpha transition so it covers and then leaves the "mask"

Comment: @MaKo, I understand that, an image can be placed as a UIView. But I need the image should contain a 'center' portion open, wherein the control like 'slide bar' would fit in open area and be still active.

Comment: @MaKo, Ultimately, with your suggestion to use UIView, I could obtain the result I required. Thanks for your suggestion.